# use of undeclared identifier 'RD16'

Tags: c, pic, mplab, xc8

I am trying to set the TMR1 T1CON register for a PIC18F4550 but I am getting an error related to the RD16 bit.I am getting :

```
config.c:17:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RD16'
RD16 = 1;
^
1 error generated.
```

Acording to datasheet :

> RD16: 16-Bit Read/Write Mode Enable bit
>
> 1 = Enables register read/write of Timer1 in one 16-bit operation
>
> 0 = Enables register  read/write of Timer1 in two 8-bit operations

I read some posts and it should be correct.Im ussing XC8 and MPLab

my config.c complete code :

```
#include <xc.h>
void configPIC(void){
    T3CCP2:T3CCP1 = 01;   //TMR1 para CCP1    
    CCP1M0 = 0;           //Captura flancos de subida
    CCP1M1 = 1;
    CCP1M2 = 0;
    CCP1M3 = 1;
    CCP1IF = 0 ;          //Bandera de Captura CCP1
}

void timer1config(void){
    //TMR1 Config Registros   
    TMR1ON = 1;
    RD16   = 1;
    T1RUN  = 0;     //Usar reloj interno
    TMR1CS = 0;     // FOSC / 4
    T1CKPS1:T1CKPS0 = 00;
    T1OSCEN = 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume `use of undeclared identifier` means you are using a variable before having declared it

Comment: This is hardly a proper [mcve] - what are the 16 previous lines in the config.c

Comment: T3CCP2:T3CCP1 = 01;  That's not valid C-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RD16 **bit** is inside T1CON **byte** / register. The `xc.h` header specifies it as a bitfield member inside T1CONbits structure like this, taken from [here](https://github.com/JamesDunne/eminor2/blob/master/v2/controller/PIC/p18f4550.h):

```
extern volatile near union {
  struct {
    unsigned TMR1ON:1;
    unsigned TMR1CS:1;
    unsigned T1SYNC:1;
    unsigned T1OSCEN:1;
    unsigned T1CKPS0:1;
    unsigned T1CKPS1:1;
    unsigned T1RUN:1;
    unsigned RD16:1;
  };
  struct {
    unsigned :2;
    unsigned NOT_T1SYNC:1;
  };
} T1CONbits;
```

You should use it like this:

```
T1CONbits.RD16 = 1;
```

as all the other bits inside any register on PICs devices. Inspect the [p18f4500.h](https://github.com/JamesDunne/eminor2/blob/master/v2/controller/PIC/p18f4550.h) header to find out the names for all registers.

PS. Anyway, I would like to add, that if you are using PIC18 for a custom project using free xc8 compiler or sdcc compiler, don't do it, put all your pic devices into the trash bin and buy cheaper, faster, better and simpler STM32 devices. Unless you are using paid xc8 compiler or working for a project where PICs are a must, don't waste your time.

Comment: Same opinion - waste of time. I love PIC errata pages. DS looks great, when you look at the errata (which is almost same size as the regular documentation) you see all the nice features being blown by the errata pages. Actually they should name the advertised feature lists a "wish list" not the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#include <xc.h>
void configPIC(void){
    T3CONbits.T3CCP2   = 0;      //TMR1 para CCP1    
    T3CONbits.T3CCP1   = 0;
    CCP1CONbits.CCP1M0 = 0;      //Captura flancos de subida
    CCP1CONbits.CCP1M1 = 1;
    CCP1CONbits.CCP1M2 = 0;
    CCP1CONbits.CCP1M3 = 1;
    PIR1bits.CCP1IF    = 0;      //Bandera de Captura CCP1
}



void timer1config(void){
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON  = 1;
    T1CONbits. RD16   = 1;
    T1CONbits.T1RUN   = 0;      //Usar reloj interno
    T1CONbits.TMR1CS  = 0;      // FOSC / 4
    T1CONbits.T1CKPS1 = 0;
    T1CONbits.T1CKPS0 = 0;
    T1CONbits.T1OSCEN = 0;
}
```

You may want to have a look at the Microchip Code Configurator. It could do a lot of configuration work for you.